# This state not updating after a method returns in react

Tags: reactjs

I currently have a class in react.  For the sake of saving space I'm only putting the code that is relevant.

```
  this.state = {
    orgID: null,
    memberID: null,
  }

checkAuthUser = () => {
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    this.props.firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(authUser => {
      if(authUser) {
        console.log(authUser);
        resolve(authUser);
      } else {
          reject(new Error("Not authorized"));
        }
      })
  })
  .then( authDetails => {
    this.props.firebase.getOrgID().on('value', snapshot => {
      const setSnapshot = snapshot.val();
      const getOrganizationID = Object.keys(setSnapshot)[0];
      this.setState({ memberID: authDetails, orgID: getOrganizationID })
    })
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
}

  render() {
    if (this.state.orgID == null) {
    try {
      this.checkAuthUser();
      console.log(this.state);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
    }
```

In the class there's a method `checkAuthUser` . using firebase it checks whether a user has been signed in or not.  If the user is signed in I console.log the object `authUser`.  The console.log does log authUser details so I know it's hitting firebase and then returning the details.  After I have a call to get some info from firebase.

I had added some console.logs to also confirm that it was running.  However after the data comes back the console.log in render doesn't run anymore.  The only console.log I get is the first initial state.  What am I missing here?

Comment: You need to check if you are getting `getOrganizationID` in `checkAuthUser` function.

Comment: `console.log(this.state);` is in a conditional with `if (this.state.orgID == null)` - therefore the `console.log(this.state);` isn't running after `orgID` is no longer `null`? is there some JSX that isn't shown here (because of the MVCE)?